# Can't uninstall Architect edition and install the Community edition

Tags: c++builder

I have installed a C++Builder trial version of the Architect edition, but could not uninstall it and install the Community edition. I used the license manager and tried to delete the license, but still it would not allow me to install a different edition. I tried to delete every reference in the registry, and deleted the directory, with no luck.